# Cppunit for Nucleus RTOS

Tags: c++, unit-testing, rtos

In my project i need to do unit testing on my c++ code by using Cppunit. problem is code is based on real time operating system " NUCLEUS". Please help me out by letting me know how to do unit testing using cppunit when the platform is not windows but rtos.

Comment: Hello, I am new with this technology, could you please share how can set-up development environment...also if any guideline to start with basic example...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create stubs or mocks of the OS calls and run the tests on Windows as you would normally.

It is useful in this case to also use a static analysis tool with the emphasis in portability issues since assumptions about data sizes and byte order for example may cause code that works on one platform to fail on another.  If you target and your test platform share common data sizes and byte order you are in a better position in that respect.